# How to test sail.js controller with user logged in with passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tdd, sails.js, supertest

I try to unit test my sail.js controller that requires user to be logged in. My current test is:

```
var request = require('supertest'),   // I try to use 'superagent', this changes nothing
    user = request.agent;

describe('SomeController', function() {
    // login user first of all
    before(function(done) {
        user(sails.hooks.http.app)
            .post('/user/login')
            .send({username: 'hellocat', password: '123456789'})
            // request works well by itself, 
            // it does not return error and return normal response.
            .end(function (err, res) {
                // then I try to save cookies of logged in user to it agent
                user(sails.hooks.http.app).saveCookies(res);
                done();
            });
    });

    // let test something
    it('must return "ok" when user is logged in or "wtf" if opposite', function(done) {
        user(sails.hooks.http.app)
            .get('/user/me')
            .end(function(err, res) {
                console.log(res.body);
                // no need to expect something, user is not logged in (
                done();
            });
    });

});
```

Before hook works well and my user is logged in at the end of request. But in test it is not. 
I lift sails application before all the test started to run. Similar tests that is not require authorization work well.
I guess the error is probably in cookie saving or wrong understanding of how to use supertest agents. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I finally found my error. `request.agent` function does not return singleton. So each call of `user(sails.hooks.http.app)` is actually new agent and new user. To make this test snippet work I should do something like this

```
var request = require('supertest'),
    agent = request.agent;
```

And call agent once in describe section:

```
describe('SomeController', function() {

    var user;

    before(function(done) {
        user = agent(sails.hooks.http.app);
        user
            .post('/user/login')
            // ...
    // ...
```

Comment: this did not work for me... I'm still getting a 403 forbidden response

Comment: @MattWestlake are you using `user` for other requests? I mean that after login you should `user.get() ...` instead of using `sails.hooks.http.app`

Comment: I switched over to using `supertest-as-promised` and they recommended using `request = require('supertest-as-promised').agent(sails.hooks.http.app);` which is working